# I need to change wordpress text with jQuery but I don't have ID or Classes

Tags: wordpress

I am translating a wordpress page with WPML, but magically woocommerce buttons won't show on the website, and I decided to translate with jQuery, but the problem is, when I manage to translate the button, it breaks the website. I don't find wordpress button's id or something..
Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce elements can sometimes be hard to modify, i already did such a thing by using the Loco translate plugin, you can select what plugin or theme you directly want to translate. Maybe with WPML, you have translated something that broke woocommerce display, try this with Loco translate